# nHibernate inverse mapping

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent

I have a single object (object A) which contains a collection of object B. I have my mapping classes (fluent) setup with this all the working, the problem is when trying to save. I want to perform a single save call and for this to then also save all object B's. Again, this works EXCEPT that nHibernate isn't assigning the foreign key variable on object B's after saving object A.

I believe inverse is used in such situations(?) but it doesn't appear to be working for me. Object A has the mapping for the collection:

```
HasMany(x => x.Responses)
            .Inverse()
            .KeyColumn("[ParentID]")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.All()
            .AsBag();
```

And object B has the reference to object A:

```
References(x => x.Entry, "[ParentID]")
            .LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.None();
```

I thought the Inverse would be on the object B side but References doesn't contain an Inverse function.

Thoughts?

Cheers

Comment: The mapping looks ok. Are you sure that `B.Entry` contains a reference to `A` before you call `Save()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem exists in adding objects B to collection from object A.
Look here http://eashi.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/nhibernate-inverse-attribute/

Answer (score 0):

I use to create `AddChild` method on parent class like this:

```
public class Parent
{
     public void AddChild(Child child)
     {
         child.Parent=this;
         this.ChildrenCollection.Add(child);
     } 
...
```